# Should I change draw order?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating mobile racing(in space) game and it's first person so there is always big cockpit occluding big part of scene.  Can I somehow use the fact that I know it to optimize rendering? I have heard that draw call order can be changed, but I don't know how exactly it would work.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I added some info after you accepted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called "Occlusion Culling". [Here is a guide from the Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html) explaining how it works and how to set it up.

NOTE: This only culls static objects, if your cockpit moves with the player objects covered by the cockpit will not be culled by using this method. If you want to do occlusion culling with dynamic objects you need to get a 3rd party asset from the store like [InstantOC](http://frenchfaso.blogspot.it/p/instantoc.html), it even has a "Mobile Aircraft Controls" prefab (Note, I have never used InstantOC but I have heard good things about it).